# Integration by parts for double integrals

Tags: calculus, integration

In my economics course, I need to show that:
\begin{align}
   \int_{\underline{\theta}}^{\bar{\theta}}\left\{\theta q(\theta)-c(q(\theta))-\int_{\underline{\theta}}^{\theta} q(t) d t\right\} d F(\theta) &= \int_{\underline{\theta}}^{\bar{\theta}}\left\{\theta q(\theta)-c(q(\theta))-\frac{1-F(\theta)}{f(\theta)} q(\theta)\right\} f(\theta) d \theta
\end{align}
Essentially I must show that using integration by parts that
\begin{align}
     \int_{\underline{\theta}}^{\bar{\theta}}\left\{\int_{\underline{\theta}}^{\theta} q(t) d t\right\} d F(\theta) = \int_{\underline{\theta}}^{\bar{\theta}}\left\{(1-F(\theta)) q(\theta)\right\} d \theta
\end{align}

Where $F'(\theta) = f(\theta), F(\bar{\theta}) = 1, F(\underline{\theta}) = 0, q(\underline{\theta}) = 0$. Assume $F$ is continuous and differentiable. Here $F$ is a CDF, $f$ is a pdf, $q$ is a "cost function".

However I am not sure how to use integration by parts for a double integral. I tried doing it but failed. Any help would be appreciated.
My attempt:

\begin{align*}
    \int_{\underline{\theta}}^{\bar{\theta}}\left\{\int_{\underline{\theta}}^{\theta} q(t) d t\right\} d F(\theta) &=
    \int_{\underline{\theta}}^{\bar{\theta}}\left\{\int_{\underline{\theta}}^{\theta} q(t) d t\right\} f(\theta)d \theta \\
    &= \int_{\underline{\theta}}^{\bar{\theta}} \left[q(t)F(\theta) \right]_{\underline{\theta}}^{\theta} d \theta - \int_{\underline{\theta}}^{\bar{\theta}} F(\theta) \left\{\int_{\underline{\theta}}^{\theta} \frac{d}{dt}q(t) d t\right\} d \theta \\
    &= \int_{\underline{\theta}}^{\bar{\theta}} (q(\theta)-q(\underline{\theta}))F(\theta) d \theta - \int_{\underline{\theta}}^{\bar{\theta}} (q(\theta)-q(\underline{\theta}))F(\theta) d \theta \\
    &= 0
\end{align*}

Comment: I can't see $\underline{\theta}$ in the original problem. But, you've used it for lower limits in both inner & outer integrals. Is that a typo?

Comment: Strange, I have typed it correctly but it's not showing. In both integrals the lower limit is $\underline{\theta}}$. I have worked out how to solve this question, thanks for the help anyway.